# FabricJS - Javascript - PHP : Export SVG save on server

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I use FabricJS library to draw on a canvas. Then I would like to save the canvas on the server side. I don't know how to save it in a .svg file. 
What I know is :

1. Create export data
2. Send it to the PHP script with AJAX
3. Create the file on the server in this PHP script

The problem is that I don't know excactely how to do that. Which FabricJS function have I to use to export SVG datas ? 
Which PHP function have I to use to write the file ?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save an image of the canvas as SVG but not the canvas itself.

If you want to save the canvas itself, you can use json. I've used it to both save/load on a server-side database and also on the client file system. You will find many examples of this by searching for JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON())